# Работа с Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript

Делаю лист с линками, где нужно добавлять, удалять, изменять и лайкать линки.

**Вопрос 1**: Почему при добавлении линки появляются только после перезагрузки страницы?

**Вопрос 2**: Почему при изменении линка он не сохраняется после перезагрузки страницы?

**Вопрос 3**: Не могу правильно организовать систему лайков. Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку like изменялся бекграутд заголовка и линки должны сохраняться посе обновления страницы.

**app.component**:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Link } from './linksArr';
import { LINKS } from './links/links.component';
import { LinksComponent } from './links/links.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <linkaAdder-app></linkaAdder-app>
    <app-links></app-links>
  
    `,
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'My favorite links';
}
```

**link-list.service**:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LinkListStoregeService } from './link-list-storege.service';
@Injectable()
export class LinkListService {

  private linkList = [
    { titleL: 'habrahabr', link: 'https://habrahabr.ru/' },
    { titleL: 'facebook', link: 'https://www.facebook.com/' },
    { titleL: 'w3school', link: 'https://www.w3schools.com' },
    { titleL: 'angular', link: 'https://angular.io/' },
    { titleL: 'github', link: 'https://github.com/' },
  ];

  constructor( private storage: LinkListStoregeService) { }

  getLinkList() {
    return this.storage.get();
  }
  addItem(item) { 
    return this.storage.post(item); 
  }
  removeItem(item) {
    return this.storage.destroy(item);
  }
  likeItem(item, classN){
    console.log(item);
    console.log(classN);
    return this.storage.like(item, classN);
  }
}
```

**link-list-storege.service**:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
const storageName = 'aah_link_list';
const defaultList = [
  { titleL: 'habrahabr', link: 'https://habrahabr.ru/' },
  { titleL: 'facebook', link: 'https://www.facebook.com/' },
  { titleL: 'w3school', link: 'https://www.w3schools.com' },
  { titleL: 'angular', link: 'https://angular.io/' },
  { titleL: 'github', link: 'https://github.com/' },
];
@Injectable()
export class LinkListStoregeService {
  private linkList;
  constructor() {
    this.linkList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storageName)) || defaultList;
  }
  /**
   * get items
   * @returns {any[]}
   */
  get() {
    return [...this.linkList];
  }
  /**
    * Add a new todo item
    * @param item
    * @returns {any[]}
    */

  /**
  * Syncronize the local storage with the current list
  * @returns {any[]}
  */
  private update() {
    localStorage.setItem(storageName, JSON.stringify(this.linkList));

    return this.get();
  }
  /**
   * Add a new todo item
   * @param item
   * @returns {any[]}
   */
  post(item) {
    this.linkList.push(item);
    return this.update();
  }
  /**
     * find the index of an item in the aray
     * @param item
     * @returns {number}
     */
  private findItemIndex(item) {
    return this.linkList.indexOf(item);
  }

  /**
   * Update an existing item
   * @param item
   * @param changes
   * @returns {any[]}
   */
  put(item, changes) {
    Object.assign(this.linkList[this.findItemIndex(item)], changes);
    return this.update();
  }

  // remove an item
  destroy(item) {
    this.linkList.splice(this.linkList.indexOf(item), 1);
    return this.update();
  }
  like(item, classN){
    console.log(item);
    console.log(classN)
    this.linkList.item.classList.toggle(classN);
    return this.update();
  }
}
```

**link.component**:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Link } from '../linksArr';
import { AppComponent } from '../app.component';
import { LinkListService } from '../link-list.service';


export const LINKS: Link[] = [
  { titleL: 'habrahabr', link: 'https://habrahabr.ru/' },
  { titleL: 'facebook', link: 'https://www.facebook.com/' },
  { titleL: 'w3school', link: 'https://www.w3schools.com' },
  { titleL: 'angular', link: 'https://angular.io/' },
  { titleL: 'github', link: 'https://github.com/' },
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-links',
  template: `
  <div>
    <ul class="links">
      <li  *ngFor="let link of links"
        [class.selected]="link === selectedLink">
        <div class="title">
          <span class="badge">{{link.titleL}}</span> 
          {{link.link}}
        </div>
        <button (click)="likeItem(link)" class="btn like">Like</button>
        <button (click)="onSelect(link)" class="btn change">Change</button>
        <button (click)="removeItem(link)"class="btn del">X</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="selectedLink">
    <h2>{{selectedLink.titleL}} details!</h2>
    <div><label>title: </label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="selectedLink.titleL" placeholder="title"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>link: </label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="selectedLink.link" placeholder="link"/>
  </div>
  </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./links.component.css']
})
export class LinksComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private linkListService: LinkListService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.links = this.linkListService.getLinkList();
  }

  links = LINKS;
  selectedLink: Link;

  onSelect(link: Link): void {
    this.selectedLink = link;
  }
  
  removeItem(item) {
    this.links = this.linkListService.removeItem(item);
  }
  likeItem(item) {
    console.log(item);
    let classN =  'link';
    this.links = this.linkListService.likeItem(item, classN);
  }
}
```

**linkAdder.component**:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LINKS } from '../links/links.component';
import { LinkListService } from '../link-list.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'linkaAdder-app',
  template: `<div class="inputAdd">
    <input name="Link.titleL" #inputTitleL placeholder="title">
    <input name="Link.link" #inputLink placeholder="link">
    <button (click)="addLink(inputTitleL.value, inputLink.value)">Save</button>
  </div>`,
  styles: [
    `.inputAdd{
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-between;
      width: 15em;
      height: 5em;
    }
  `
  ]
})

export class LinksAdderComponent {
  links = LINKS;
  constructor(private linkListService: LinkListService){}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.links = this.linkListService.getLinkList();
  }
  addLink(title, link): void {
    let newLink;
    console.log(link);
    if (link.startsWith('https://') || link.startsWith('http://')) {
      newLink = link;
    }else{
      newLink = `http://${link}`;
    }
    this.links = this.linkListService.addItem({titleL: title, link: newLink});
  }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте отказаться от глобальной переменной ``LINKS``